# WGET Python 3.6 getting stuck

Tags: python-3.6, wget

I'm trying to download almost a thousand files from a website. Each of the files has its own URL.

I'm looping the following command while changing the url and the name of the downloaded file as newfile:

`wget.download(url, newfile)`

The download of each file starts with a .tmp file whose size keeps increasing until the entire file is downloaded. However, after downloading 5-10 files in about 10 min, the program just simply stops with the .tmp file "stuck" at the same size!

When I kill the process, delete the .tmp file and resume the program, it runs smoothly but then again stops exactly the same way 5-10 files later!

I'm using python 3.6.9

Comment: Maybe the website is throttling your activity.

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: Maybe write delays into your program so you're not bombarding the website with requests.